# HttpClient Header could not append Authorization

Tags: ionic3, django-rest-auth, angular4-httpclient

I am trying to authenticate to a Django Rest API by appending a Token to the Http Header. I already configured the server to allow Cross-Origin Resource Sharing and was able to authenticate previously using the older version of HTTP.
The problem started after I upgraded to the latest Ionic CLI (Ionic 3) and started using HttpClient module instead.

Here is a segment of my code:

```
// get token data from storage
this.storage.get('auth').then((val) => {
this.headers = new Headers();
this.headers.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
this.headers.append('Authorization', val);
console.log(this.headers.get('Authorization')) //displays: Token randomKey1244556etc 


//request
 this.http.get<any>("http://192.168.22.5/api-get-user", {headers: this.headers})
        .subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
        }, (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }, (err) => {
      this.flag = false;
    })
```

The API returns the following error:
{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}

Here is the detail of the network request sent and the server response:

[image]

However, the authentication succeeded when using PostMan using the same credentials appended to the HttpClient Header.

[image]

It seems that either the header was not sent with the request or the authorization was not appended to the header. Any idea how to solve the problem?

Note: I am also using CORS Google Chrome extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As expected, there is something wrong with the Header. I have solved the problem by customizing the request header by replacing the old header:

```
this.headers = new Headers();
this.headers.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
this.headers.append('Authorization', val);
```

to:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', val);
```

Reference: [Customizing Http Request Header](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/http-with-angular-quick-start/)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the headers...The instances of the new `HttpHeader` class are **immutable** objects. Invoking class methods will return a new instance as result.